# Remove Column Separators from default ng grid angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I am using default ui-grid and now i want to remove column separator line (the line in between 2 columns for separation) from my grid. As You can see in plunkr, name and gender is separated by a thin grayish line. i have checked various solutions but i could not remove that separator. Instead of separator i need a space between columns here is my code. How can i achieve that... [Plunkr Source](http://plnkr.co/edit/vXITsk?p=preview)

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
enableSorting: true,
enableFiltering: true,
showTreeExpandNoChildren: false,
columnDefs: [
  { name: 'name', width: '30%' },
  { name: 'gender', width: '20%' },
  { name: 'age', width: '20%' },
  { name: 'company', width: '25%' },
  { name: 'state', width: '35%' },
  { name: 'balance', width: '25%', cellFilter: 'currency' }
],
onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) {
  $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
  $scope.gridApi.treeBase.on.rowExpanded($scope, function(row) {
    if( row.entity.$$hashKey === $scope.gridOptions.data[50].$$hashKey && !$scope.nodeLoaded ) {
      $interval(function() {
        $scope.gridOptions.data.splice(51,0,
          {name: 'Dynamic 1', gender: 'female', age: 53, company: 'Griddable grids', balance: 38000, $$treeLevel: 1},
          {name: 'Dynamic 2', gender: 'male', age: 18, company: 'Griddable grids', balance: 29000, $$treeLevel: 1}
        );
        $scope.nodeLoaded = true;
      }, 2000, 1);
    }
  });
}
```

};

Comment: Cannot understand your needs, what column separator?

Comment: I mean the line in between 2 columns for separation. That's the column separator

Comment: You can see in plunkr, name and gender is separated by a thin grayish line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play with `columnDefs` and `cellClass`, [please check this](http://plnkr.co/edit/mqgJQcVYxica8OyCjZum?p=preview)

JS Snip:

```
   columnDefs: [
      { name: 'name', width: '30%', cellClass: 'noborder' },
      { name: 'gender', width: '20%', cellClass: 'noborder' },
      { name: 'age', width: '20%', cellClass: 'noborder' },
      { name: 'company', width: '25%', cellClass: 'noborder' },
      { name: 'state', width: '35%', cellClass: 'noborder' },
      { name: 'balance', width: '25%', cellClass: 'noborder', cellFilter: 'currency' }
    ],
```

CSS:

```
.noborder {
  border: none;
}
```

You can do almost the same for the header row with `headerClass`or `headerCellTemplate`

Comment: for Headers headerClass:'noborder' is not working... It still shows the border around headers

Comment: Try using `headerCellTemplate`and add the `noborder` class to the cell template